# How to flush a pipe created by pipe() on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I want to flush a pipe created by pipe() call on Linux, as i am interested only in data that will come *after* read() was called. I am trying following ioctl call:

```
ioctl_err = ioctl(G_MIDI_inout_event_pipe[0],I_FLUSH,FLUSHR);  
read(G_MIDI_inout_event_pipe[0],&event_type,1);
```

But ioctl returns ENOTTY and pipe is not flushed.
How to properly flush such stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard way to do it.

You could consider setting the non-blocking attribute on the pipe followed by a preliminary `read()` to clear the data, then reset the attribute to blocking before collecting the data you're really after.  You'd have to attempt to read at least the pipe size — which can be as small as 4 KiB or can be much larger (64 KiB on Linux, IIRC).  That's kinda fiddly, but it would 'work' with a minimal window of time between TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) — basically, the two `read` calls I'm postulating.  That shouldn't matter to you; it was data written after the start of the reading process.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried what you suggested and it works as i want it to. It is a bit of a hack, but as i can't find any other way to do it, i guess i'll have to stick to this solution.